# ColdFusion ServerFile is undefined in CFFile

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

When I try to run the following code, I'm getting the error message: `"Element SERVERFILE is undefined in CFFILE."`. I've done this a million times.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
    <cffile action="upload" fileField="fileField" destination="xxxx" 
        nameConflict="Overwrite" result="thisResult">
    <cfoutput>#cffile.ServerFile#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the [`result`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html) attribute. So instead of `cffile.serverFile`, use `thisResult.serverFile`.

> **Result** Lets you specify a name for the variable in which cffile returns the
>   result (or status) parameters. If you do not specify a value for this
>   attribute, cffile uses the prefix cffile. For more information, see
>   Usage.

Comment: `cffile.serverfile` instead of `cfide.serverfile`.