# coldfusion cffile upload how to describe the file to be uploaded

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I've never used cffile upload.  In looking at the documentation I see that the file to be uploaded is described as

Name of form field used to select the file.
Do not use number signs (#) to specify the field name.

I just cannot decipher this.  If the file to be uploaded is john.jpg, residing on the user's disk, how do I indicate that in the cffile command?

I have other questions as well, but would like to start with this very basic one.

Comment: Did the documentation you looked at not include examples?

Comment: Oh it did, but they explained nothing:  fileField = "FileContents" -- what might "FileContents" be?

Answer (score 1):

What documentation are you using? There should be an example like there is here: [`<cffile action="upload">`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html)

In this example (which I've edited), it shows that you do not reference the name of the file that the user selected, that could be anything, you reference the **name of the form field**, `fileContents`, that is used to upload the file.

```
<!--- Windows Example --->
<!--- Check to see if the Form variable exists. --->
<cfif structKeyExists(Form, "FileContents") > 
    <!--- If TRUE, upload the file. --->
    <cffile action = "upload"
        fileField = "FileContents"
        destination = "c:\files\upload\" 
        accept = "text/html"
        nameConflict = "MakeUnique"> 
<cfelse> 
    <!--- If FALSE, show the Form. --->
    <form method="post" action=<cfoutput>#cgi.script_name#</cfoutput>
         name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

        <input name="FileContents" type="file"> 
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
    </form> 
</cfif>
```

Once the `CFFILE` process completes, a collection of variables are defined in a structure named `CFFILE` (see documentation link). One of these variables is `cffile.clientFile`, which contains the name of the file that was uploaded from the user's computer.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation -- I'm starting to understand.  But where is the name of the file john.jpg that I want to upload?

Comment: See that last line in my answer? The name of the file does not exist in the value of any form field variable that you can access. It's contained in the uploaded file content, which you access using the variable cffile.clientFile, which only exists after you run CFFILE to upload the file.

Comment: Adrian,  I messed around with the code, and found for myself that the file to upload is specified in the browse button that the type=file produces.  It would have been helpful if the documentation said that.  Anyway, it's all working now.  Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the cffile command:

```
<cffile action = "upload"
        fileField = "FileContents"
        destination = "c:\files\upload\" 
        accept = "text/html"
        nameConflict = "MakeUnique"
        result = "thisResult">
```

...you would use #thisResult.clientFile# to get the original filename.
All the other fields would be available using this also.

I found this on stackoverflow:
[ColdFusion ServerFile is undefined in CFFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484724/coldfusion-serverfile-is-undefined-in-cffile)

Comment: This should be a comment.  While "late" answers are always welcome, they should add value to the thread by [contributing new information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299678/104223). The above was already covered in the [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403347/104223).